# php send curl request and wait for the response

Tags: php, curl

I am sending a curl request to a server that needs a few seconds to process the request and spit out a response.  I believe my php script is continuing on and not waiting, therefore my foreach loop based on the response is spitting out 0 results.  How can i wait for the curl transaction to complete before moving on and processing data?

```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:password");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://server/r/?dst_user__substr='user'");


  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ret = curl_exec($curl);
  $result = json_decode($ret,true);

 <<<<I need to wait until transaction is complete here>>>>

  foreach ($result['data'] as $key => $value)
  {
        //process data from $result
  }
```

Comment: AFAIK, it *will* wait for a response before continuing running the script.

Comment: Try adding `if ($ret===false) echo curl_error($curl);` after the `$ret = curl_exec...` line - it could be that the command is timing out waiting for a response.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

curl is blocking, which means that:

```
$result = json_decode($ret,true);

foreach ($result['data'] as $key => $value)
{
      //process data from $result
}
```

won't execute until:

```
$ret = curl_exec($curl);
```

is complete. You can check for errors and other issues using curl_error() and by checking the HTTP response code with curl_getinfo().

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird ! , it shouldn't happen like what you are getting. But anyways try like this..

Get a httpresponse code and then check up...

```
$curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:password");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://server/r/?dst_user__substr='user'");


  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ret = curl_exec($curl);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpcode==200)
  {
  $result = json_decode($ret,true);
  foreach ($result['data'] as $key => $value)
  {
        //process data from $result
  }
  }
```