# How to create a download file instantly without waiting for reply from PHP

Tags: php, html, http-headers

I'm using the new tag `<a download="test.csv" href="exp.php?type=5">` and my `exp.php` takes some time to calculate the results. I'd like the file to show up strait away and afcouse the data added to it as it loads/generated.

I tried these but they dont work:

```
// Required
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');

// Experimental
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Connection: close');

// ... exp.php
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $example); // Runs ~ 100-2000 times (10-5000 seconds)
```

Comment: you want the data to be downloaded while its being generated?

Comment: @Viscocent I updated my answer a bit, kindof, when the file generation is big and the user click on the `<a>` tag, he has to wait and nothing is indicated that the file is starting to download or loading.

Comment: Which is why websites have a warning that says something like, `Your download is being generated, this can take up to 10 seconds. If you feel this is an error, please 'Click Here'.`

Comment: well its time for you use `ajax`, as of what i can see, the file will only be generated when its clicked and the download will start after its generated and what you want to do is to let the user know that it is still in the process of generating it. is that correct?

Comment: @Viscocent I'm using curl and I was hoping I dont need to use ajax, its simple but was thinking PHP provides a streaming method as it output data as its generates or something like that.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817401/php-send-curl-request-and-wait-for-the-response teh problem for you the trigger is an href so thats why i adviced ajax.