# Wait for curl to finish before continuing?

Tags: php, curl

I am using an script to send date thru curl to an webshop.
In the same script there is an mail sent when this script is executed.
The mail is often send before the curl is complete and therefore missing crucial parameters.
How to change the script so the mail is send after the curl is executed?

```
// Some more curl code here

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

        // execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $data = json_decode($result);

        // close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // send mail
        require('assets/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        $mail = new phpmailer();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

// Some more mail code here
```

Comment: One option could be wrapping the curl code in a function and returning $data from it.  Then you can check if $data exists before sending the email.

Comment: *"The mail is often send before the curl is complete"* -- it doesn't happen. [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) returns when the request is complete (when it receives the response). Maybe the request doesn't complete successfully (because of the timeout you set). You should check the value returned by `curl_exec()` and decide what to do next.

Comment: You can get CURL response like this: `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpcode==200)
  { }`.. And inside this `if() {}`, you have your mail stuff.

Comment: I think you need to add this cURL option: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. This will return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php send curl request and wait for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817401/php-send-curl-request-and-wait-for-the-response)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a check on the curl response

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    // this would be your first hint that something went wrong
    die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
} else {
    // check the HTTP status code of the request
    $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($resultStatus != 200) {
        die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
    }
    else{
        //send the mail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try return transfer parameter as true to wait for the response:

```
    // Some more curl code here

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $data = json_decode($result);

    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    // send mail
    require('assets/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new phpmailer();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    // Some more mail code here
```