# Foreach with waiting

Tags: php

Good evening everyone.

I'm doing a foreach, and I curl it, getting json data.

The problem is that the curl, sometimes brings the radio feedback and sometimes takes about 30 seconds.

How do I get foreach to wait for the curl to return to pass the next parameter?

Code example:

```
foreach ($rsV as $rowV) {

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://IP/json?v1={$rowV['v1']}&v2={$rowV['v2']}");
        $response_body = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            logr('Erro na requisição com cURL #: '.$err, 'CRON', '');
            
        } else {
            $response = json_decode($response_body, true);
        }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php send curl request and wait for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817401/php-send-curl-request-and-wait-for-the-response)

Comment: @GiacomoM No, the link you sent is making the return foreach. I'm doing both, multi-value foreach passing to the curl, getting the data saving and then doing the same process again until the foreach ends.

Comment: My curl is inside the foreach, the one in the link is outside. They are different procedures.

Comment: `cURL` is blocking. That is, it waits for a response before continuing. If it's not waiting then it has a response so it's up to you to check what it's got and try again if is not what you expect.